Error reading pdf fillable form with pdfrw.PdfReader
I am trying to update a fillable PFD form with python, when trying to read it it throws an exception. Below are the code, sample pdf and the error thrown. Is there any one seen this before?
import pdfrw
pdf = pdfrw.PdfReader(input_pdf)

Error message
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pdfrw\pdfreader.py in __init__(self, fname, fdata, decompress, decrypt, password, disable_gc, verbose)
 648 
 649             if is_stream:
--> 650                 self.load_stream_objects(trailer.object_streams)
 651 
 652             while xref_list:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pdfrw\pdfreader.py in load_stream_objects(self, object_streams)
 306                 firstoffset = int(obj.First)
 307                 while objsource.floc < firstoffset:
--> 308                     offsets.append((int(next()), firstoffset + int(next())))
 309                 for num, offset in offsets:
 310                     # Read the object, and call special code if it starts

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: "ÔÞíWÎ0vætºUÐ\x8a\x13õ#v\x9f0uÀ\x08C5n¡³ñÅ³\x9d\x93\x91\x06Åo\x11j\x8eO8êøÏ\x96\x1fá?\x10ãoÂõõÀù,,1!6HêíG\x1eb\x18½'éïz²å½#¸,\x9e"```


